# Visual Studio 2008 Custom Build step output in setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, custom-build-step

I have the problem, that I want to include a outputfile from a custom build step in a setup project. Since the "add project output" option only adds the exe from the solution and not the custom output my first approach was to add it as a file. In this case the file is put under source control and write protected. Normally the files wont be checked out for building a new version, and the custom step fails and so the whole build process. So I want to dynamically use the output from the custom build step and not the file it self to resolve my problem. Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: I don't think that Visual Studio supports this. You basically need a folder synchronization feature or some sort of dynamic files.

Comment: It can't even support dynamically generated files by a relative path?  I'm gonna call the installer projects extension garbage then...

Comment: Okay turns out if I use the **Add > File** option and add the output file, even though its absolute path is displayed in the UI property pages, the path stored in the raw project file is relative, which is what I want.  What a dumb UI decision though...